# how to display images next to each other n two colums with different heights

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am having trouble with the following.  I want to be able to display an image gallery in two columns.  The images are of different heights.  I have tried using the masonry method with the column count.  That works great but the issue is because the site needs to be responsive as soon as I resize it shows everthing in 1 column.. but the images are not in the same order, due to me using columns rather than rows...

So this is the code I am using

```css
 .left {
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
        margin: 1px;
    }
    .right {
        float: right;
        width: 45%;
    }

    .test{
        margin-bottom: 10px;

    }
    .test:after {
        clear: left;

    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="left test">
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>              

    <div class="left">
      <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="left test">
        <img src="4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>              

    <div class="left">
      <img src="5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="left test">
        <img src="6.jpg" alt="">
    </div>              

    <div class="left">
      <img src="7.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="left test">
        <img src="8.jpg" alt="">
    </div>  
  </div>
```

The issue I have shown in the image below.
[image]

So image 7 should be displayed under image 5 and image 8 should be displayed where image 7 currently is.

What am I doing wrong?  Has to be only CSS, no JS

If I use column-count, then the issue is when it is in responsive.. it shows images in the following order 1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 4, 6, 7 and not 1, 2,3....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't clear the floats on `:after` but on the elements themself.

**Example**

```
.test:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Are u sure? I made a test case: http://codepen.io/skeurentjes/pen/wJPavv?editors=1100#0

Comment: so that worked but the issue is can you see the margin between block 4 and 6.... I want 6 to be moved up... just underneath 4.. the gap is too big